# Error 'value.is is not a function' when checking if a checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to ensure at least 1 checkbox in a group always remains checked, but I'm having difficulty.

I have multiple checkboxes whose name starts with `post_type[`. The function runs for the `on('change')` call just fine, with the problem occurring when I check to see if the input is a checkbox that is checked, where I get the following error.

> `value.is` is not a function

Can someone please help me troubleshoot my code? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function($){

    $('input[name^="post_type["]', '#site-search').on('change', function(){

        var checks = $('input[name^="post_type["]');
        var one_checked = is_one_checked(checks);

        if(one_checked === false){
            $(this).attr('checked', 'true');
        }

    });

});

function is_one_checked(checks){

    var checked = false; // Wheteher or not at least one box is checked (false by default)

    $(checks).each(function(key, value){
        if(value.is(':checkbox') && value.is(':checked')){
            checked = true;
        }
    });

    return checked;

}
```

Comment: why are you not using $(this)   ?

Comment: Because I didn't know I needed too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `value.is(':checked')` doesn't work is because in the loop, `value` is passed as the raw DOM object. `.is()` is a jQuery method, so you'd have to wrap `value` in a jQuery object in order to use it:

`$(value).is(':checked')`

Comment: Thank you, that works. And thanks for the explanation as to why I need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
 $(checks).each(function(key, value){
    if($(this).is(':checkbox') && $(this).is(':checked')){
        checked = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(this)`, not `value`, in the loop

```
$(checks).each(function(key, value){
    if($(this).is(':checkbox') && $(this).is(':checked')){
        checked = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

specify attr in your html  checked="checked"  then why not using .attr :

```
if($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox' && $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
        $(this).attr('checked','checked')
    }
```